# getting "<unknown>:0: error: merge-module command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" when compiling release

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I am getting the error: :0: error: merge-module command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is done when using private pod framework. this error doesn't occur when compiling release only on debug.

I have the source code of the framework if the error is there.

using Xcode 9.1 with swift 3.2.